# C++ a way to have a typedef template to a member function?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, typedef, member

Title pretty much says it all!

Is there any pretty/simple way to do this? Since function pointers can't point to member functions and a member function needs to know the class the members belong to but in this case there is no such information since the class the function comes from will differ. Only standard library please!

```
template <class A>
typedef void (A::*Function)(Parameters p);
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve where this is a step to the solution? There may be a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try wrapping it in a struct like this:

```
template <class T>
struct method_ptr
{
  typedef void (T::*Function)(Parameters p); 
};

class A
{
public:
  void foobar(Parameters);
};


// ...
method_ptr<A>::Function pfoobar = &A::foobar;
```

Comment: Some compilers will complain if typename is not added before method_ptr<A>::Function (for example GCC).

Comment: @xorguy that depends whether you're using it in a template context where it can be a dependent name. If you use it in a non-template context, like in a regular function this will work without `typename`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it but I've run into problem with this solution. I'll create another question for that though!

Answer (score 4):

Untested, but this should work with a C++11 compiler:

```
template <typename T>
using Function = void (T::*)(Parameters p);
```

Now the interesting question is what is the problem for this to be the solution.

Comment: I agree this should be the solution for C++11 or above. Or the type